# redirection code does not work with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have jquery code to redirect to another method of controller but it doesn't seems to work. following is the code. can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

```
$.ajax({
           cache: false,
           url: "/EmployeeInfoLinq/EditEmployee",
           data: { id: ID },
           async: false,
           dataType: 'json',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (response) {
               if (confirm('Are you sure you want to edit record for this employee?')) {

                   window.location.href = "/EmployeeInfoLinq/EditEmployeeLinq";
               }
           }

       });
```

Confirm message box appears but next line does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try with this:

```
window.location.href = "../EditEmployeeLinq";
```

what seems to me that your current url contains `"/EmployeeInfoLinq/"` and you have currently available at some other controller but you want to navigate to other controller containing same class so you just have to use `../` to get back one level up and move to `"/EditEmployeeLinq"`

or you can try this in your ajax success method:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var page = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
window.location.href = page+"/EditEmployeeLinq"
```

Comment: I had also checked with this code but its not working. I had changed the link to http://google.co.in but its also not working. It only works when we debug upto this redirection line and then press F10 key of keyboard.

Comment: @Audy that's what i want to see that what kind of url you are having currently? and what should be done in your case?

Comment: @audy oops my mistake perhaps i have not made it clear. Your current browser url where you have your application running? like `http://localhost:4444/yoursiteurl`

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = 'http://address.com';
```

or

```
location.replace('http://address.com'); // <-- no history saved.
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
in mvc application we can navigate to particular action from view using Url.Action which accepts methodName,ControllerName

```
window.location.href='@Url.Action("EditEmployeeLinq","EmployeeInfoLinq")';
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer; this may answer the question, but it provides no guidance to the original poster.